# Kendo grid removes row, but does not call destory URL

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid where I'm trying to add a delete feature. My datasource looks like:

```
var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: Router.action("Admin", "GetScansForMailItem", { mailItemIdnt: detailinit.data.MailItemIdnt }),
            dataType: "json"
        },
        destroy: {
            url: Router.action("Admin", "DeleteScan"),
            type: "post"
        }
    },
    model: {
        id: "ScanIdnt",
        fields: {
            ScanIdnt: {editable: false, nullable: false}
        }
    },
    pageSize: 5
});
```

I added the model part because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21450852/1938826) answer, however it made no difference.

The actual grid looks like:

```
 .kendoGrid({
     dataSource: datasource
     scrollable: false,
     sortable: true,
     pageable: true,
     editable: "inline",
     columns: [{
         field: "ScanIdnt",
         title: "Scan ID"
     }, {
         field: "CreatedDate",
         title: "Created",
         template: "#= kendo.parseDate(CreatedDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd') #"
     }, {
         field: "ScanDocumentRelativePath",
         title: "File Path",
         template: "<a href='/CAMP/Admin/Download?scanIdnt=#= ScanIdnt #'>#= ScanDocumentRelativePath.substring(1) #</a>"
     }, {
         field: "ScanUserIdnt",
         title: "Scanned By"
     },{
         command: "destroy",
         title: ""
     }]
 });
```

Strangely, clicking the delete button removes the from the gird on the UI, but there is absolutely no Ajax call is made the the `destroy` URL. I can't seem to figure out why. Any ideas?

**EDIT** I'd like to point out that this grid is in fact a nested grid inside of another grid (like [here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy)) I discovered that the parent grid handles actually makes a call, but to the wrong function. For some reason, it clicking delete on a to level item calls the read function of the nested grid, however, the nested grids do nothing

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console after you click the delete button?

Comment: @Supersnake nope, absolutely nothing.

Comment: Take a look at your grid code again. The spelling for your dataSource is wrong.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I changed that after I pasted the code on here because the datasource is actually returned via a function. It's correct in the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out (sorta). While I think there were many issues with my code and the grid, It seems that when it came down to it, Kendo didn't like how I had my data.

In the Kendo docs related to hierarchical grids, the data for the child grid is stored in a field of the data for the parent. For example, given the following JSON:

```
"ParentItems": [ 
    {
        "Id": 12345 ,
        "Name": "Test1",
        "ChildItems": [
            {"Id": 1, "Name": "Test"},
            {"Id": 2, "Name": "Test"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 12346 ,
        "Name": "Test2",
        "ChildItems": [
            {"Id": 1, "Name": "Test"},
            {"Id": 2, "Name": "Test"}
        ]
    }
]
```

In the parent grid, each `ParentItem` would display it's respective `ChildItems` in the child grid.

On the other hand, I was pulling both data sets separately. Basically, I pulled the `ParentItem`s like:

```
"ParentItems": [
    {
        "Id": 12345,
        "Name" : "Test1"
    },
    {
        "Id": 12346,
        "Name" : "Test2"
    }
]
```

And then made a second request to pull the child items, based on the parent's id.

```
"ChildItems": [
    {"Id": 1, "Name": "Test", "ParentId": "12345"},
    {"Id": 2, "Name": "Test", "ParentId": "12345"}
]
```

I was able to modify the server side code to serve the data like in the very first example and managed to get things working. The specific document that helped me out can be found [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/edit-master-row-data-in-detail-template)